# A question about dissecting spherical triangles

Tags: mg.metric-geometry

Do there exist spherical triangles which are not isoceles but are the union of a finite collection of
(two or more) congruent triangles with pairwise disjoint (and non-empty) interiors?

Answer (score 6):

Yes. Take any equilateral triangle and divide it into six congruent triangles barycentrically. The union of three of those parts is a non-isosceles right triangle.

Comment: (unless that equilateral triangle was right-angled)

Comment: Thanks for your very neat answer. I had tried to decompose many
non-isoleces spherical triangles without sucess until I began to
think that the answer to my question might be negative. But I did
not think of gluing some congruent triangles together to see if I
could form a non-isoceles triangle out of them.

Comment: So, can you decompose a big triangle into several congruent little triangles in such a way that none of the triangles (big or little) are isosceles and none of them have any right angles?

(I don't know the answer.)

Comment: I wonder whether the problem would become any easier if you imposed
the two restrictions of not being isoceles and of not containing any
right angles only on the BIG triangle?